# How much disk space does a clean Ubuntu Studio installation need?

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-studio, system-requirements

I'm considering installing Ubuntu Studio. I can't decide whether to make a clean installation or to install its programs on my existing Ubuntu to save disk space. I'm currently low on free disk space.

I just want to know About how much disk space would Ubuntu studio take? Just like Ubuntu maybe? Or less?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A minimum of 7.6 GB are required for a clean **ubuntu-studio-12.04** install:

[image]

Comment: hmmm okay thanks alot! That's what I needed to know :) ...hey do you use Ubuntu Studio? ...if so, tell me, did you need to install more "space hungry" stuff?

Comment: well it really depends on your needs, this [article](http://www.howtoforge.com/the-perfect-desktop-ubuntu-studio-12.04) is a good start even if everything mentioned is purely optional

Comment: yep, If you are using it for graphics/music/video you will need a lot more space. That and I don't think it installed LibreOffice by default(at least on 13.10 version i'm using).

Comment: well can you give me an estimate or maybe a range? ... for one that doesn't need a full operating system out of Ubuntu Studio. Just it's "studio" powers. Just your personal suggestion please :) @Mateo

Comment: oh and @SylvainPineau, I'd be happy with yours too :D

Comment: @MinaMichael I was saying it depends what you want to do with it, It would not be good to give it 10GB just to find out that it wouldn't store more than a few min. of media, or not even a memory card of pictures...

Comment: but I can put my media in another partition @Mateo

Comment: ...hey how did you know I thought of giving it 10 gigas?!!! XD